# Submit multiple form using jquery

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

Is there any way to submit multiple forms using ajax  ?

for eg form id="form1" and form id="form2"

both the forms will be submitted separately as needed.

to be more specific i am using [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) for my form submission.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
$('#form1, #form2').submit();
```

after having AJAXified them of course:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form1, #form2').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                alert('thanks for submitting');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

After your update it seem that you are using the `jquery form plugin`. In this case you could force the AJAX submission by invoking the `ajaxSubmit` method on the 2 forms like this:

```
$('#form1, #form2').ajaxSubmit();
```